# Setting data for member in class fails with template error

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes like this

```
template <class T>
class CData
{
   std::vector<T> data;
   public:
      void SetData(std::vector<T> vt){data.assign(vt.begin(),vt.end());}
};

template <class... T>
class CDataHolder
{
   std::tuple<Data<T>...> m_data;
   //... m_data construction
   public:
    template<class T> 
    void init_data(std::vector<T> d) 
    {
        init_data_helper(d,std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>{}); 
    }
   private:
    template<std::size_t... index>
    void init_data_helper(std::vector<T> d, std::index_sequence<index...>)//ERROR HERE
    {
        (std::get<index>(m_data)).SetData(d);
    }
};
```

I would like to call the `SetData` method of `CData` class from  `CDataHolder` class method after `m_data` object is constructed. The error I have got is `parameter pack must be expanded in this context`.

Comment: Did you try `std::index_sequence<...index>`?

Comment: can you give the complete exact error you get please?